# Is it OK to post a story-identification where you knew the answer at the time when you wrote it?

Tags: discussion

As many of you know, I write a lot of `story-identification` questions. I've had it commented on from time to time, including that I have a handful where I've also provided the answer after having done further research. ^_^ Just to be perfectly clear, all of these cases were ones where I did not know the answer before I started the question, or even before I submitted the question. However, the question is, is such a practice allowable?

In general, [we support people posting questions and answering simultaneously](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1196/interesting-trivia-questions-to-which-you-already-know-the-answer), and [it's allowable under general Stack Exchange policy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), but it seems to me that it's a kind of iffy practice for `story-identification` where it's so terribly subjective, not to mention that there really is no possibility of a "better answer" being posted. On the other hand, it does help others who might look for the story in the future. And, under more selfish motives, it's a way to expose others to the work in question (one could introduce a question relating to the story, but one doesn't always spring to mind and, in my experience, they tend to be largely ignored unless someone else is already of the fandom).

Comment: Looking for something more current than the [last discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3352/1027) on this?

Comment: This is a different Query,  more specific to your question: http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/422739/story-identification-questions-asked-and-answered-by-the-same-user-at-the-same-ti

Comment: @AncientSwordRage: ... I remembered those ones, but thought that I didn't find the answer until later that day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question already got an answer of sorts previously,  but the query stoked by DVK doesn't actually answer the question.

This [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/422739/story-identification-questions-asked-and-answered-by-the-same-user-at-the-same-ti) covers the exact case where on posting the question,  you select the self-answer Tick Box. I query a proxy if this,  but making sure the asking and answering time is the same *down to the second*.

Of the current four,  two are yours. One is very well received, and none are closed.

But from your comment it sounds like these were likely asked in good faith:

> I remembered those ones, but thought that I didn't find the answer until later that day.

But I think it stretches the limit of the sites purpose,  to only post to:

> expose others to the work in question.

In that case,  I think it's a step to far. Otherwise,  go ahead.